# Can't find a codec for ArrayOperators$ArrayToObject after upgrading to java 17 and spring boot 3

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, java-17

After upgrading to Java 17 and **spring boot 3**, along came an upgrade to the latest spring data mongodb, **4.1.0** version.
It seems all is good except one case of using the ArrayOperators$ArrayToObject from the spring data Aggregation expressions. My code deals with Mongo Template directly and the **aggregate **method

```
mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, TRANSLATABLE_COLLECTION_NAME, TranslationTexts.class)
```

This gives now:

```
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for CodecCacheKey{clazz=class org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ArrayOperators$ArrayToObject, types=null}.
```

My mongodb server is 4.2 version, but tried on 6.0 and the same issue occurs.
I do not understand why this particular class only has an issue with the codec. I'm using other operators from **ArrayOperators** class, and those still function.
I can work around this, but I want to understand if anything for this changed. Unfortunately the migration docs don't really mention anything like it, and it seems like a really common functionality that should still be functional.
Does anyone know why it would be problematic ?
Also, this is the only custom mongoconfig that I have, that I even tried removing, and still no success:

```
    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() {
        MongoDatabaseFactory customMongoDatabaseFactory = mongoDatabaseFactory();
        MappingMongoConverter converter =
                new MappingMongoConverter(
                        new DefaultDbRefResolver(customMongoDatabaseFactory),
                        new MongoMappingContext());
        converter.setTypeMapper(
                new DefaultMongoTypeMapper(null)); // remove _class field from serialization
        converter.setCustomConversions(mongoCustomConversions());
        converter.setMapKeyDotReplacement(MAP_KEY_DOT_REPLACEMENT);
        converter.afterPropertiesSet();
        return new MongoTemplate(customMongoDatabaseFactory, converter);
    }
```